# typedef, DLLEXPORT, __stdcall help in C

Tags: c++, c

Can anyone please provide me the full meaning of the following 2 lines of codes?

> > typedef void DLLEXPORT __stdcall (*DLL_Inquiry) (char *cDriverName, int *iDriverType, int *iDriverBUS, int *iNumberOfChannel);
> >
> > DLL_Inquiry       DRV_PH_Inquiry;

I know that `DLLEXPORT` is to export a function from the DLL, `__stdcall` is the *x86* argument passing convention.

But still I am not able to get the whole meaning of these 2 lines. May be I am confused with use of function or function pointer in `typedef`.

Comment: _"`_STDCALL` is the x86 argument passing convention."_ There are many calling conventions for the x86. `stdcall` is the one used by the Win32 API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DLL_Incuiry` is a typedef for a pointer to function that takes arguments `(char*, int*, int*, int*)` and returns no value (return type `void`). The function also uses the calling convention defined by DLLEXPORT and __stdcall.

`DRV_PH_Inquiry` is a variable of that type, so if you have function `foo`:

```
void DLLEXPORT __stdcall foo (char *cDriverName, int *iDriverType, int *iDriverBUS, int *iNumberOfChannel);
```

you can then do the assignment:

```
DRV_PH_Inquiry = foo;   // DRV_PH_Inquiry now points to the function foo
```

Comment: _STDCALL is a calling convention, but DLLEXPORT is not a calling convention i think?

Comment: I think DLLEXPORT expands to something that makes the compiler/linker export the function/object when building a DLL, and to nothing when not building a DLL.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef void DLLEXPORT __stdcall (*DLL_Inquiry) (
    char *cDriverName, int *iDriverType, int *iDriverBUS, int *iNumberOfChannel);
```

This defines a typedef for `DLL_Inquiry` to be a function pointer.

- The function receives the parameters listed, no need to explain those any further.
- The function has `void` return type.
- The calling convention is `__stdcall`.
- The definition of `DLLEXPORT` is not standard. That will be found in your code. Most likely there will be a header file that defines `DLLEXPORT` as a macro. For instance, when compiling the DLL, on the Windows platform, it might evaluate to `__declspec(dllexport)`. In any case, only you can know for sure what the definition of `DLLEXPORT` is.